# Endianness Work-around Needed

Tags: c++, c, pointers, endianness, cpu-architecture

Consider the following piece of code:

```
#include "stdio.h"

typedef struct CustomStruct
{
  short Element1[10];
}CustomStruct;

void F2(char* Y)
{
  *Y=0x00;
  Y++; 
  *Y=0x1F;    
}

void F1(CustomStruct* X)
{
  F2((char *)X);
  printf("s = %x\n", (*X).Element1[0]);
}

int main(void)
{
  CustomStruct s;
  F1(&s);

  return 0;
}
```

At run-time, by the end of calling the function `F1`, I get different results by using different compilers.

`(*X).Element1[0] = 0x1f00` in some compiler and `(*X).Element1[0] = 0x001f` with another one.

It's clear to me that it's an endianness issue.

Is there any compiler option or work-around to use so that I get `(*X).Element1[0] = 0x001f` regardless the used compiler?

Comment: Show us how you populate `Element1`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what you mean. Do you mean that you need the actual body of F2? I think it useless as I guarantee that by the end of F2 you have Y[0]=0x00 and Y[1]=0x1F.

Comment: You are trying to provide that guarantee.  We are trying to show you how, but unless you give us real code to work with, we can only guess about what you're doing.

Comment: I have updated the code so we can better understand each others :)

Comment: Wait, now I'm confused.  `0x00` and `0x1f` are only 1 byte wide, as is `*Y`, so there is no endianness to account for here. Also, is `*Y=0x1F;` a typo?  Was this meant to be `==`?

Comment: The endianness problem is on X not Y.
The above code prints 0x1f00.
When flashing this code to an embedded target and debugging (a uController) (*X).Element1[0] = 0x001f.

Comment: It actually prints `1f00` on my Intel system, but OK, I think I got you now.

Answer (score 6):

[Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) is not a compiler issue, nor even an operating system issue, but a platform issue.  There are no compiler options or "workarounds" for endianness.  There are however conversion routines so that you can normalize the endianness of stored data.

The `ntoh` routines [documented here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ntohl) will reorder the bytes pointed to from network order (big endian) to host order (either big or little, depending on the type of host).   There are also `hton` functions that go in the opposite direction, from host order to network order.

If you want to normalize the bytes stored in your data structure, you need to do it yourself either when you store the data or when you try to read it.

Here are function templates I wrote for `ntohx` and `htonx` that are generalized on the type of data store, be it a 2 byte, 4 byte or 8 byte type:

```
template<class Val> inline Val ntohx(const Val& in)
{
    char out[sizeof(in)] = {0};
    for( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(Val); ++i )
        out[i] = ((char*)&in)[sizeof(Val)-i-1];
    return *(reinterpret_cast<Val*>(out));
}

template<> inline unsigned char ntohx<unsigned char>(const unsigned char & v )
{
    return v;
}
template<> inline uint16_t ntohx<uint16_t>(const uint16_t & v)
{
    return ntohs(v);
}

template<> inline uint32_t ntohx<uint32_t>(const uint32_t & v)
{
    return ntohl(v);
}

template<> inline uint64_t ntohx<uint64_t>(const uint64_t & v)
{
    uint32_t ret [] =
    {
        ntohl(((const uint32_t*)&v)[1]),
        ntohl(((const uint32_t*)&v)[0])
    };
    return *((uint64_t*)&ret[0]);
}
template<> inline float ntohx<float>(const float& v)
{
    uint32_t const* cast = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t const*>(&v);
    uint32_t ret = ntohx(*cast);
    return *(reinterpret_cast<float*>(&ret));
};

template<class Val> inline Val htonx(const Val& in)
{
    char out[sizeof(in)] = {0};
    for( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(Val); ++i )
        out[i] = ((char*)&in)[sizeof(Val)-i-1];
    return *(reinterpret_cast<Val*>(out));
}

template<> inline unsigned char htonx<unsigned char>(const unsigned char & v )
{
    return v;
}
template<> inline uint16_t htonx<uint16_t>(const uint16_t & v)
{
    return htons(v);
}

template<> inline uint32_t htonx<uint32_t>(const uint32_t & v)
{
    return htonl(v);
}

template<> inline uint64_t htonx<uint64_t>(const uint64_t & v)
{
    uint32_t ret [] =
    {
        htonl(((const uint32_t*)&v)[1]),
        htonl(((const uint32_t*)&v)[0])
    };
    return *((uint64_t*)&ret[0]);
}
template<> inline float htonx<float>(const float& v)
{
    uint32_t const* cast = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t const*>(&v);
    uint32_t ret = htonx(*cast);
    return *(reinterpret_cast<float*>(&ret));
};
```

Comment: Of course, ntoh/hton only work to guarantee that one representation will be in Big Endian and one representation will be usable by your machine regardless of endianness; it provides no direct mechanism to guarantee one representation will be in Little Endian.

Comment: @Medinoc: Right, that is true.

Answer (score 2):

If `F2()` is receiving a `char *`, then it must be doing something pretty strange in order to cause endian-related problems.

These only happen when accessing *more* than one `char` at a time, unless it's manually doing such accesses while being broken. Is it casting it's argument back to `short *` or something?

In short, show more code.

Comment: I have added a compiling code of the problem now :)
If you tried it, it prints 0x1f00. 
But when flashing this code to an embedded target and debugging (a uController) (*X).Element1[0] = 0x001f.