# c++ read (big endian) binary float

Tags: c++, floating-point, binary, endianness

I have a binary file that contains n single-precision values. I know that the format used when writing data was big-endian. When I read in the data into a float vector ('mainvector' in the code below), by default, the data is read in according to little-endian format. I use the following to read data:

```
ifstream inputfile("filepath",ifstream::in|ifstream::binary)
inputfile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&mainvector[0]), n*4);
inputfile.close()
```

There is a lot of discussion on endianness and conversion on stackoverflow itself. However, this is the first time I have to deal with the endianness issue and all the information available is a bit overwhelming. In the process I learned that the bytes are reversed (big vs. little endian).

Is there a one-liner that I can incorporate to change the default little-endian treatment of my binary data to big-endian, or post-process my *mainvector* in order to get the original data ? or would I need to manually reverse byte-order of each of the n values ?

**UPDATE**: It appears that there is no one-liner for this. Individually changing the byte order is the way to do it! How to do that is discussed here by Mats and elsewhere (e.g. [here](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/writing-endian-independent-code-in-c-r2091)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to reverse each value individually. So something like this would work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    const int n = 34;
    float mainvector[n];

    std::ifstream inputfile;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
    unsigned char temp[sizeof(float)];
    inputfile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(temp), sizeof(float));
    unsigned char t = temp[0];
    temp[0] = temp[3];
    temp[3] = t;
    t = temp[1];
    temp[1] = temp[2];
    temp[2] = t;
    mainvector[i] = reinterpret_cast<float&>(temp);
    }
}
```

You may be able to use some form of built in function to swap the order, but that will make it compiler specific...

Comment: I thought `reinterpret_cast` can only cast to a pointer type...

Comment: @0x499602D2: The code I just edited in compiles with gcc 4.6.3 with -Wall - it complains that `mainvector` isn't used, but other than that no problems. I'm not able to test it, as I don't have a "big endian float file".

Comment: @Mats: Works, incl. the usage of 'reinterpret_cast'.

Comment: The `unsigned char temp[sizeof(float)]` buffer is not guaranteed any particular alignment, so on quite a few CPUs the `mainvector[i] = reinterpret_cast<float&>(temp)` will SIGBUS or similar.  There are many alternatives/workarounds, including having a larger buffer and using [`std::align`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align) to find a suitably aligned offset therein.

Answer (score 0):

Unix systems have [routines for this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) (and other systems may as well). Code is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17448956/298225). Your compiler must support type-aliasing (so that a reference to a float may be cast to a reference to an int and vice-versa).

Comment: It seems your link to the routine is not relevant... Maybe [this](http://linux.die.net/man/3/endian) is the one you meant.